# Prove that if sets $A$ and $B$ are closed and bounded then $A+B$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, compactness

> Prove that if sets $A$ and $B$ are closed and bounded then $A+B$ is closed

I know that $A$ and $B$ are closed and bounded, then they are sequentially compact, so $A+B$ also sequentially compact, thus it is bounded and closed.

However, I'm asked to show that $A+B$ is closed without using the result that it's sequentially compact.

I try to let $c$ be the cluster point of $a_n +b_n$, I want to show that $c \in A+B$, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $A$ and $B$ are closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb R$, then they are compact.

Assume now that $z_n\in A+B$ and $z_n\to z$, we need to show that $z\in A+B$. Then $z_n=x_n+y_n$, with $x_n\in A$ and $y_n\in B$. Since $A$ is compact, then there exists a converging subsequence $x_{n_k}\to x\in A$. But this implies that
$$y_{n_k}=z_{n_k}-x_{n_k}\to z-x,
$$
and as $B$ is closed, then $y=z-x\in B$.

Finally, $z=x+y\in A+B$.

**Note.** Only one of the sets $A$ and $B$ has to be bounded.

Comment: $y_{n_k} =z_{n_k}-x_{n_k}$ are you imply that $z_{n_k} =y_{n_k}+x_{n_k}$, so $y_{n_k} and x_{n_k}$ are one to one correspond? for example, what if $z_3 = x_1 + b_4$?

Comment: $z_n=x_n+y_n\Rightarrow z_{n_k}=x_{n_k}+y_{n_k}\Rightarrow y_{n_k}=z_{n_k}-x_{n_k}$ - I can not follow your question.

Comment: $z_n, x_n,and y_n$ are sequence which can have many sub sequence. From your equation it seem like $z_3=a_3 + b_3$, while it doesn't necessary to be that way. for example $z_n= 1,2,3,4$, $x_n=0,1$,$y_n =4,1,2$, so from this example, $z_1=x_1 +y_2$

Comment: I am sorry, but I can not understand.

Comment: @Diane Yiorgos is saying that for each $n$, by virtue that $z_n \in A+B$, there exist $x_n \in A$ and $y_n \in B$ such that $z_n = x_n + y_n$.  The sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are not defined before hand they are being defined this way at each $n$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Surely you mean that only one of the sets has to be bounded. They both have to be closed.

Comment: @ZainPatel I corrected it. *Only one has to be bounded*.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis  I have to prove $A+B$ is closed.                                                                        We Know, $A+B \subset \overline{A+B} \tag{1}$ For converse, Let $x \in \overline{A+B}$, $\exists$ {$x_n$}  in $A+B$ which converges to $x$. We also know that $x_n=a_n+b_n, a_n \in A , b_n \in B$. $x=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$=$\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n+b_n)$, $\implies$ $x \in A+B$. What is wrong in this argument? How boundedness play role?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis May I  know What is wrong in the proof?